# SQL display months when Count is 0

Tags: sql, date, count, sql-server-2008-r2, datepart

I was wondering if someone could help me...

I have the following SQL query (have shortened this down as its a large union query)

```
  SELECT [  Month   ],
sum(total) 
 from
(select datename(month,Resolved1Date) as '  Month   ',
COUNT(case when 
fileDescription not like 'test%' 
and Issue1Description ='Escalated' then 0 else 1 end)   as 'total'   
FROM         complaint_1 WITH (nolock) INNER JOIN
             Case WITH (nolock) ON Case.ref = complaint_1.ref 
WHERE     
Resolved1Date >=DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)
Resolved1Date  <= dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0)
group by datename(month,Resolved1Date), datepart(month, Resolved1Date)
)x                     
group by  [  Month   ]
order by  [  Month   ] desc
```

the query counts all cases where the resolved date is between 1st day of current year and less than current month. my problem is if there are no results for a month it excludes the month, I would like my results to return something like:-

```
jan   5
feb   10
march 7
apr   0
may   2
```

can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you not just add another WHERE clause for Resolved1Date = 0?

Comment: You should format your query.  You should also fix the logic.  For instance, the `case` statement in the `count(case)` isn't doing anything.  You should also tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: removing the case statement doesn't help with what i'm after,i think the issue is around the count as im counting a date field and then stating where the sate field is between two values, I need it to display a month as 0 if no matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a set of Months as the first table in the from clause, and join your query to this. Then you will get a result for every month.
I have similar issues with financial reporting where I need results for all months and financial years.
I have used the DATENAME function to ensure consistent results with your query. 
If you want data in Month order (Jan - Feb - Mar) you may not want to order by Month as this would be alphabetical, you would need to include a sort field.

```
SELECT M.[  Month  ] AS [  Month  ]
      ,SUM(ISNULL(x.total,0)) AS [Total] -- x.total will be null for months with no transactions.
  FROM -- Set of Months (need one record for each month)
     (SELECT * FROM (VALUES(DATENAME(month,'2015-01-01'),1)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-02-01'),2)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-03-01'),3)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-04-01'),4)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-05-01'),5)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-06-01'),6)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-07-01'),7)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-08-01'),8)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-09-01'),9)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-10-01'),10)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-11-01'),11)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-12-01'),12)) AS Mnth("  Month  ",MnthSort)) AS M
LEFT OUTER JOIN  -- Your from clause goes here.
     (SELECT * 
        FROM (VALUES (DATENAME(month,'2015-01-01'),5)
                    ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-02-01'),4)
                    ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-02-01'),6)
                    ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-03-01'),7)
                    ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-04-01'),0)
                    ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-05-01'),1)
                    ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-05-01'),1)
              ) AS data("  Month  ","total")) x ON x.[  Month  ] = M.[  Month  ]
GROUP BY M.[  Month  ], M.MnthSort
ORDER BY M.MnthSort
```

I ran this on SQL Server 2008 - R1

The first part of the from clause in the query defines the set of months in a table format with one row returned for each month (Run this to see results):

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES(DATENAME(month,'2015-01-01'),1)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-02-01'),2)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-03-01'),3)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-04-01'),4)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-05-01'),5)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-06-01'),6)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-07-01'),7)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-08-01'),8)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-09-01'),9)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-10-01'),10)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-11-01'),11)
                     ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-12-01'),12)) AS Mnth("  Month  ",MnthSort)
```

The LEFT OUTER JOIN after it is to link the results of your query to each month, so each month gets a total. An outer join is used because there isn't a total for every month.

The Query using your sql from above would be like:

```
SELECT M.[  Month  ] AS [  Month  ]
      ,SUM(ISNULL(x.total,0)) AS [Total] -- x.total will be null for months with no transactions.
  FROM -- Set of Months (January - December), ensures one record for each month
     (SELECT * FROM (VALUES(DATENAME(month,'2015-01-01'),1)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-02-01'),2)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-03-01'),3)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-04-01'),4)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-05-01'),5)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-06-01'),6)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-07-01'),7)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-08-01'),8)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-09-01'),9)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-10-01'),10)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-11-01'),11)
                          ,(DATENAME(month,'2015-12-01'),12)) AS Mnth("  Month  ",MnthSort)) AS M
LEFT OUTER JOIN  -- Your Query included from here...
    (SELECT datename(month,Resolved1Date) as '  Month   ',
            COUNT(CASE WHEN fileDescription NOT LIKE 'test%' 
                        AND Issue1Description ='Escalated' THEN 0 ELSE 1
                  END) as 'total'   
       FROM complaint_1 WITH (nolock)
            INNER JOIN Case WITH (nolock) ON Case.ref = complaint_1.ref 
      WHERE     
            Resolved1Date >=DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)
            Resolved1Date  <= dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0)
      group by datename(month,Resolved1Date), datepart(month, Resolved1Date)
     ) x on x.[  Month  ] = M.[  Month  ]

GROUP BY M.[  Month  ], M.MnthSort
ORDER BY M.MnthSort
```

Comment: thanks for your post @nxb, could you explain what you mean by "Create a set of Months as the first table in the from clause" im fairly new to SQL and this is starting to send me mad!

Comment: Edited post to answer question, hope that is clearer.

Comment: ahh got it, I had commented out the 'Left outer join" and put my query in, and was receiving incorrect syntax messages. I didn't understand it was used to link result of my query to months, makes sense now. thank you for your help @nxb :-) really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can create the temporary table and left join from that.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @Helper TABLE 
(
  TheDate datetime
)

DECLARE @StartDate datetime
SELECT @StartDate = '01.01.2015'

WHILE @StartDate < DATEADD(day,7,GETDATE())
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Helper (Thedate) VALUES (@StartDate)

  SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDate)

END
```

I hope it helps.